# PHP/cURL - GeoNames - TimeZone API - Cannot get response from API

Tags: php, php-curl, geonames

I'm currently doing a project for a coding course.
I'm trying to pull data from the GeoName TimeZone API to display on a page but I'm very stuck and I've not been able to narrow down what the problem is. Is anything able to help.

Here is my code -

index.html -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>API Name</th>
                <th>API Description</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1. Timezone</td>
                <td><p id="tabledescriptions">Description</p>
                    <p>The timezone at the given longtitute and latitude.</p>
                    <label for="longitude">Enter the Longitude: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="long" name="longtitude">
                    <label for="latitude">Enter the Latitude: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude">
                </td>
                <td><button id="buttonrun1">Submit 1</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2. Name</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><button id="buttonrun2">Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2. Name</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><button id="buttonrun3">Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p id="tabledescriptions">Result of Timezone API Call</p></td>
                <td><p id="sunrise"></p><br><br>
                    <p id="sunset"></p><br><br>
                    <p id="country"></p><br><br>
                    <p id="timeZone"></p><br><br>
                    <p id="timeNow"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>

    <footer>


    </footer>
</html>
```

main.js

```
    $('#buttonrun1').on('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "libs/php/getTimeZone.php",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        longitude: $('#long').val(),
        latitude: $('#lat').val()
      },
      success: function(result) {
  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
  
          $('#sunrise').html(result['data'][0]['sunrise']);
          $('#sunset').html(result['data'][0]['sunset']);
          $('#country').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
          $('#timeZone').html(result['data'][0]['timezoneId']);
          $('#timeNow').html(result['data'][0]['time']);
  
        }
      
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // your error code
      }
    }); 
  
  });
```

getTimeZone.php

```
 <?php

    // remove for production

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=' . $_REQUEST['latitude'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['longitude'] . '&username=t90moy';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode;
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

    ?>
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You are going to have to give us a bit of a clue as to what is not working

Comment: There is no array and they are objects so `$('#sunrise').html(result['data'][0]['sunrise']);` should be `$('#sunrise').html(result.data.sunrise);`

Comment: Also if you tell jQuery `dataType: 'json',` then you will get JSON back which will be converted into a javascript obect for you, so `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` try `console.log(result);` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section os wrong

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
  
          $('#sunrise').html(result['data'][0]['sunrise']);
          $('#sunset').html(result['data'][0]['sunset']);
          $('#country').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
          $('#timeZone').html(result['data'][0]['timezoneId']);
          $('#timeNow').html(result['data'][0]['time']);
  
        }
```

You are passing back JSON that will be converted to an javascript object so

```
console.log(result);
  
if (result.status.name == "ok") {

  $('#sunrise').html(result->data->sunrise);
  $('#sunset').html(result->data->sunset);
  $('#country').html(result->data->countryName);
  $('#timeZone').html(result->data->timezoneId);
  $('#timeNow').html(result->data->time);

}
```